# MATLAB: Mapping Bits to a Carrier Wave

Tags: arrays, matlab, signal-processing

I have an array of bits, such as the one below, and I need to put a carrier wave on top of them.  The question is: Is this possible to do without looping?

For example, suppose you are using Frequency-Shift-Keying.  If the bit is a "1" then the signal should be a sine wave with a frequency of 10,000 Hz, and if the bit is a "0" then the signal should be a sine wave with a frequency of 8,000 Hz.

Bit-Array:

```
bits = [0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
```

Looping Code:

```
for i = 1:length(bits)
   if bits(i) == 1
      signal = [signal sin(2*pi*10000*t)]
   else
      signal = [signal sin(2*pi*8000*t)]
   end    
end
```

It would be nice if I could perform this all in a single operation with no looping.

Thanks.

Comment: is `t` a vector or a scalar? does it change within the loop? what is the size of `signal` at the end of the loop?

Comment: If you have enough memory, you could always unroll the loop by the number of bits times the bit time in length.

Comment: @d'o-o'b: "bits" never changes, so I guess that makes it a scalar. length(signal) = length(bits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `t` is a scalar, then you can replace your for loop with a single-line vectorized solution:

```
signal = sin(2*pi*t.*(8000+2000.*bits));
```

However, if you're doing [frequency-shift keying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-shift_keying), it seems like you should be expanding each `0` or `1` in your `bits` vector into a sine wave with a given duration and frequency. For example, to create a modulated signal with 4 sine periods (0.1 msec) at 8 kHz for each `0` and 5 sine periods (0.1 msec) at 10 kHz for each `1`, you can use the function [KRON](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/kron.html) like so:

```
t = 0:5e-6:4.95e-4;
signal = sin(2*pi.*(kron(bits,10000.*t)+kron(~bits,8000.*t)));
```